# Passing variables from Django view to template remains empty

Tags: python, html, django

I'd like to pass a variable from my Django view to my template, but the below code doesn't work. I don't get any errors, my template just remains blank.

view

```
def view_name(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    today = now.strftime("%A, %b %d, %Y")
    return render(request, "dash.html", {"today": today})
```

template

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3">
<div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">HELLO {{ today|safe }} GOODBYE</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: When I pass other values in my HTML they are showing up:
[image]

Comment: blank as in no content at all (no `<div>`s, or blank as in `{{ today|safe }}` is blank?

Comment: As a sanity check, try putting special text before and after the variable, like so: `<p class="card-text"> HELLO {{ today|safe }} GOODBYE </p>`  If you see HELLO and GOODBYE on the page, then at least you know it's (mostly) working.  If you don't see them, then likely you've made a silly mistake like loading the wrong page.

Comment: @JohnGordon: When I do that I can see the Hello and Goodbye, but not my value itself. And there is only one html page that I am using so I know I am not loading a wrong page or something.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Only the {{ today|safe }} is blank.

Comment: `render` is what? `from django.shortcuts import render`? Or something else maybe?

Comment: @pako: It is indeed from the Django render shortcuts. I also have some other graphs on that page that do work with that render shortcut

Comment: Try to pass other variable like `foo` with value as `test` and render it inside your template. This will verify if problem is with the `render()` or with `today` variable.

Comment: @pako: I replaced the today with something else (a simple string) but it still remains empty. So I assume it has something to do with my render

Comment: I found the issue, only the first URL in urls.py is actually called in my template.